# Can anybody explain why using \multicolumn changes the width of the four-column tabular environment?

Tags: tables, multicolumn, width

The following example typesets five `tabular` environments. All five `tabulars` share the same definition,

```
\begin{tabular} { | p{1.67cm} |  p{1.67cm} | p{1.67cm} | p{8.0cm} |}
```

However, the overall widths of the five tabulars differ considerably, depending on how various `\multicolumn` statements are employed. Can somebody explain why this is happening?

```
\documentclass[preview,border=100pt]{standalone}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0.2cm}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular} { | p{1.67cm} |  p{1.67cm} | p{1.67cm} | p{8.0cm} |}\hline
\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{ HEAD}\\\hline\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{A}& C & D\\\hline
A & B & C & D\\\hline
\end{tabular}

\bigskip
\begin{tabular} { | p{1.67cm} |  p{1.67cm} | p{1.67cm} | p{8.0cm} |}\hline
\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{ HEAD}\\\hline\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{A}& C & D\\\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{A} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{B}  & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{C}  & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{D} \\\hline
\end{tabular}

\bigskip
\begin{tabular} { | p{1.67cm} |  p{1.67cm} | p{1.67cm} | p{8.0cm} |}\hline
\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{ HEAD}\\\hline\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{A}& C & D\\\hline
\end{tabular}

\bigskip
\begin{tabular} { | p{1.67cm} |  p{1.67cm} | p{1.67cm} | p{8.0cm} |}\hline
\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{ HEAD}\\\hline\hline
\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{A} & D\\\hline
\end{tabular}

\bigskip
\begin{tabular} { | p{1.67cm} |  p{1.67cm} | p{1.67cm} | p{8.0cm} |}\hline
\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{ HEAD}\\\hline\hline
\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{A}\\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please clarify your question.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of editing the title of your posting to clarify its objective. Feel free to revert if you believe that I misunderstood your objective.

Answer (score 5):

If every cell is re-specified by a `\multicolumn` then the original column specification in the tabular is not used at all. That is the case in all your examples, so the only effective column specifications are `c` which will use the natural width of the text of the cells in each column.

Answer (score 5):

The key to understanding what's going on is to appreciate fully the meaning of the fact that `\multicolumn` directives take three arguments:

- Arg 1: the number of columns to which the directive applies. This number can be as small as `1` and as large as `n`, where `n` is the total number of columns in the tabular-like environment.
- Arg 2: The column type -- observe the singular form of the word "type" -- to be used for the combined column. It's important to realize that this column type completely *overrides* the underlying column type (or types) that is specified via `\begin{tabular}{...}`. In particular, `\multicolumn{1}{c}{...}` overrides whatever the basic column type may be for the current column and replaces it with `c`.
- Arg 3: The contents of the combined column.

For the sake of completeness, I'll also note that whereas the `p` column type has a fixed width, columns of type `l`, `c` and `r` have no *ex ante* fixed width. Instead, their widths will be that of the material they contain.

Let's apply this to each of the five `tabular` environments. First, a picture (slightly modified from your code, mainly to ease cross-referencing) to establish the five different widths:

[image]

- In the first tabular (with header `HEAD1`), there are cells in each of the four columns without `\multicolumn` statements. The overall width of each cell is therefore governed by the width of the associated `p` column type (1.67cm for the first three columns, and 8cm for the final column).
- In the second tabular, the material in columns 1 and 2 is never without a `\multicolumn` statement. In both data rows, the `c` column type is employed by the `\multicolumn` statements. Hence, LaTeX never gets to apply the "underlying" `p` column type for either of the first two columns. That's why the width of the second tabular is less than that of the first.

  Observe that the widths of the first two columns are given by the widths of the underlying letters (`A` and `B`, respectively) plus `2\tabcolsep`; the combined width of the first two columns is therefore the sum of the widths of the letters `A` and `B` plus `4\tabcolsep` plus `\arrayrulewidth`.
- In the third tabular, there are only three "effective" columns, as there are no cells with separate material for the first two columns. The width of the effective first column is therefore given by the sum of the widths of the letters `A` and `B` plus `2\tabcolsep`.
- The fourth tabular contains effectively *just two* columns. The underlying `p` column types of the first three columns are never used. Only the fourth column's underlying "p" type gets any use.
- The fifth and final tabular effectively contains *just one* column, whose column type is `c`. Observe that the four underlying `p` column types are never used. That's why the fifth `tabular` is so much narrower than the first four are.

The main take-away should be that `\multicolumn` is quite powerful; in fact, it's a lot more powerful than one might at first give it credit. In particular, it's important to realize that the consequences of the fact that the column type specified in the second argument of `\multicolumn` overrides the underlying column types completely.

---

```
\documentclass[preview,border=100pt]{standalone}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0.2cm}
%%\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|p{1.67cm}|p{1.67cm}|p{1.67cm}|p{8.0cm} |}
\hline
\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{HEAD1}\\
\hline\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{AB} & C & D\\
\hline
A & B & C & D\\ % all four underlying column types get used in this row
\hline
\end{tabular}

\bigskip
\begin{tabular}{|p{1.67cm}|p{1.67cm}|p{1.67cm}|p{8.0cm}|}
\hline
\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{HEAD2}\\
\hline\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{AB} & C & D\\ % "p" column type is used only in columns 3 and 4
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{A} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{B}  & 
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{C} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{D} \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\bigskip
\begin{tabular}{|p{1.67cm}|p{1.67cm}|p{1.67cm}|p{8.0cm}|}
\hline
\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{HEAD3}\\
\hline\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{AB} & C & D\\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\bigskip
\begin{tabular}{|p{1.67cm}|p{1.67cm}|p{1.67cm}|p{8.0cm}|}
\hline
\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{HEAD4}\\
\hline\hline
\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{ABC} & D\\ % "p" column type is used only in column 4

\hline
\end{tabular}

\bigskip
\begin{tabular}{|p{1.67cm}|p{1.67cm}|p{1.67cm}|p{8.0cm}|}
\hline
\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{HEAD5}\\
\hline\hline
\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{ABCD}\\ % "p" column type isn't used anywhere
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```